# How to traverse a n*n matrix without touching ( i , j ) where i=j or i=j+1

Tags: algorithm, matrix, traversal

Given an *n*n* matrix, in each round, choose 2 sets *X* and *Y* (*X,Y* are subsets of *[n]*), for all *i* in *X* and for all *j* in *Y*, we must not have *i=j* or *i=j+1*. How to design an algorithm to find these *X's* and *Y's* so that we can traverse this *n*n* matrix without touching *( i , j )* where *i=j* or *i=j+1*, in *O(logn)* time? Thanks.
e.g. When *n=3*, round one: *X={1},Y={2,3}*, round two: *X={1,2},Y={3}*, round three: *X={3},Y={1}*.

Comment: `i = j` is referring here all the diagonal elements. I do not understand which elements `i = j + 1` are referring here though.

Comment: The line "under" the diagonal line.

Comment: Pretty sure that you can't do it with O(logn) rounds. In fact, it seems to me that it takes exactly `n` rounds. For your example, the rounds would be `X={1}, Y={2,3}`, `X={2}, Y={3}` and `X={3} Y={1}`. And in general, the set X has exactly 1 value for `i`, and the set Y has all of the values `j` that are allowed for that `i`.

Comment: What do you mean with things like "round" or "touching"? Also, what have you tried, what effort have you shown? Point is, that looks like homework and just dumping that here is frowned upon. As new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You are traversing a `n*n` matrix without touching `i = j` and `i = j + 1`. The number of except elements are `n` for (`i = j`) and `n-1` (for `i = j + 1`). Hence the number of elelemts for traversing is `n^2 - (n +‌ n - 1) = n^2 - 2n + 1`. Hence, you can't do it in `O(log(n))`.

However it is simple to iterate for the specified elemetns (in python):

```py
from itertools import chain
for i  in range(n):
    for j in chain(range(0, i-1), range(i+2, n)):
        # do something on (i,j)
```